# How to import .m3u playlist exported from Windows

Tags: rhythmbox, playlists

I exported my my iTunes playlists to .m3u files before I got rid of Windows 7 completely.

Now I would like to import the playlists into Rhythmbox, but can't. My playlists contain Windows file names (e.g. D:\music....) instead of Linux file names (e.g. /mnt/music....).

The music is still stored on the exact same disk and folder as it was under Windows.

I need a script to convert the file names, can anyone help?

Comment: Open the .m3u file in gedit and do a couple of Find-and-Replaces. Save under a different name in case you mess things up. Surely, you could write a script that substitutes path names, but, unless you have dozens of playlists, that would take up more time.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks Jos. I had a good look at the file and it is as simple as a find and replace in the original .m3u file.

1. Edit the .m3u file with a text editor, e.g., `gedit`
2. Replace the first part of each music file in the playlist file, e.g., `D:\music`, with `/mnt/music`.
3. Replace the remaining `\` with `/`.
4. Save the file.
5. In Rhythmbox, click the plus sign (+) below Playlists and navigate to the edited .m34 file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `vim` using substitution.

Open the file in `vim` and enter the following characters `:%s/D:\\music\\/\/mnt\/music\//g`.

Or with `gedit` using `Find and Replace...` from the settings menu found near the top right. Where you're "finding" `D:\music\` and replacing it with `/mnt/music`